# App Update issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Hi everybody I have an issue in my app. I need to determine if my app has has been updated to some point. I found out with this method how I can get the current version

```
 NSString *first = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

 NSString *second = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

If the app is updated from itunes, Who var is changed to determine my app has been updated because I prove by modification from xcode in the Targets>Summary>Version to prove .The first var changes but the second does not change.

What I have to select the first or the second,  and how I can prove this?

Comment: Please learn to write readable English. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Jake King please edit the post if english is not readable... much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks @TejeshwarGill my english is not good i'm working on this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but this code can tell you if your app has been updated by storing version information in NSUserDefaults.

```
- (BOOL)wasUpdated {
    // access NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // get previous version number from defaults
    NSString *previousVersion = [defaults stringForKey:@"previousVersion"];

    // get current version number from info plist
    NSString *currentVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    // check against previousVersion being nil
    if (!previousVersion) {
        // set current version to previous version
        [defaults setObject:currentVersion forKey:@"previousVersion"];

        // previousVersion didn't exist and can't be checked, return NO
        return NO;
    }

    // return YES if the versions are not the same
    if (NSOrderedSame != [previousVersion compare:currentVersion]) return YES;

    // return NO if they are the same
    return NO;
}
```

Hopefully that's what you needed. Tell me if I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Thanks @enbr you now how i can prove this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I know the code will work. To run it you can use an if statement like this. if ([self wasUpdated]) { // was updated}

Comment: Thanks @enbr This is ok But I want now how can I prove that like in xcode manual change the version? how can I prove this works, because if I change in xcode directly the version with `CFBundleVersion ` happen nothing but with `CFBundleShortVersionString` I can see the version changed, so how can I prove if I chose `CFBundleVersion ` Thanks.

Comment: CFBundleVersion is what my code is using. You can see changes to CFBundleVersion in Info.plist. It is called "Bundle version".